# Error capturing or sending screenshot: TypeError: Failed to fetch at takeScreenshot

Tags: image, http, server, https, html2canvas

I have created a project that captures a div's screenshot and posts it to the server. This project works fine when I run it on my PC, but when I deploy it, it gives me an issue.

Initially it gave the issue about
**Blocked loading mixed active content**

Which was resolved when I added this to my index.html file

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests" />
```

Error capturing or sending screenshot: TypeError: Failed to fetch at takeScreenshot

Below code is working fine on my PC.

```
async function takeScreenshot() {
    try {
        if(document.getElementById('content').innerText== " "){
            return;
        }

        const container = document.querySelector('.sign-in-container');
        const canvas = await html2canvas(container);
        const screenshotDataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        const blob = dataURLtoBlob(screenshotDataUrl);
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('screenshot', blob, 'screenshot.png');
        document.getElementById('content').innerText=""
        await fetch('http://meditradesoft.in:5000/upload', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
        });

        console.log('Screenshot captured and sent to server.');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error capturing or sending screenshot:', error);
    }
}

// Function to convert data URL to Blob
function dataURLtoBlob(dataURL) {
    const arr = dataURL.split(',');
    const mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1];
    const bstr = atob(arr[1]);
    let n = bstr.length;
    const u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
    while (n--) {
        u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
    }
    return new Blob([u8arr], { type: mime });
}
```

Please tell how to resolve it. It was giving issue when I was doing it on React now I switched to Basic again its giving an issue.

**Is it related anything about HTTP or HTTPS cause my server is on HTTP not HTTPS ?**
If Yes then Please some ways to fix it !